# How to configure Apache running in a docker container to log both to files and console at the same time?

Tags: apache, logging, docker

I have a docker container with Apache running in it. I want Apache to save logs to files system (access and error log separately and rolling). Additionally I want to see live logs with `docker logs` command.

How to configure Apache running in a docker container to log both to files and console at the same time?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `tee` command pipe to the standard output stream (`/proc/1/fd/1`) of Apache process and to `rotatelogs` like this:

```
CustomLog "|$/usr/bin/tee -a /proc/1/fd/1 | bin/rotatelogs -l -n 30 logs/access.log 10M" common
# Apache captures stderr itself and pipes it to itself. As this would make an infinite loop, we use stdout here for Docker (/prod/1/df/1)
ErrorLog "|$/usr/bin/tee -a /proc/1/fd/1 | bin/rotatelogs -l -n 10 logs/error.log 2M"
```